# 2x Thunderbolt Display color issues

Tags: display, thunderbolt-display

I just got my 2 Thunderbolt displays for my MacBook Pro Retina.

I connected the 2 screens on one Thunderbolt port by using the Thunderbolt chain solution. (connecting screen 2 to screen 1 and screen 1 to the MBPR).

Those screens all work fine, but the color calibration is a big question mark.
While the screen 2 is showing a clear white, screen 1 is having this yellowish white which I dont really like. How can I fix that? Color profiles in the System Preferences → Displays seem to me that I can only calibrate screen 2…

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed the problem. What I did is: under System Preference - > Displays go to Color Tab. I calibrated both the displays differently to match color with each other.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! Whilst this may answer the question, it would be preferable to include the essential steps of the solution here. How did you exactly calibrate the displays in order to make them match?